# request.getParameter() not receiving the parameter value in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, httprequest

I am trying to send `book id` of a book from a jsp file to another jsp.To do this i wrote this code inside `BookSearch.jsp`.

```
String bid=rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println("bid in search is "+bid);
            String url=rs.getString(3);
            System.out.println(url);
            String ref="/Summer/BookData.jsp?id="+bid+"";
            out.println("<a href="+ref+">"+"<img src="+ url + "style"+"=width:350px;height:350px>"+"</a>");
```

Now to receive the parameter i wrote this code inside `BookData.jsp`.

```
String bid=request.getParameter("bid");
System.out.println("value of bid is "+bid);
```

But in the console, the `println` statements prints these--

```
value of bid is null
```

Why `BookData.jsp` is unable to receive parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a parameter you call `id` in the url, which you give the value of the variable `bid`. You either need to look at the parameter `id` in BookData.jsp too or you need to name the parameter `bid` in the url too.